# cdi-unit tests failing with recent maven-failsafe-plugin versions

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin, cdi-unit

After updating maven-failsafe-plugin from 2.18.1 to version 2.22.2, cdi-unit (4.1.0) tests started to fail with the error:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: 
Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private com.company.test.FooBar
```

Tried also version 2.19.1 with the same result. Maven version 3.6.1. Java 1.8.0_162-b12. Works with java 11.

Comment: Did you find a solution or created a bug report for it?

Comment: Please create a bug report at https://github.com/cdi-unit/cdi-unit and attach a test project.